# Swing application menu name not displaying correctly in Java 1.8

Tags: java, macos, swing, jmenubar

Okay, so I've done Swing applications before, and I know if you want to display a different name for the application menu (the one on Macs that usually have a "Preferences" and "Quit" option), you have to use: `System.setProperty("com.apple.mrj.application.apple.menu.about.name", "App name");` and it must be executed before the JFrame is created. I've done this, but it continues to show my Main class' name as the menu name, as if I didn't write that line of code at all. I googled for this issue, but couldn't find anything useful, and then I just searched on here, but everyone who had a similar issue was running Java 1.5, 1.6, or 1.7. So I thought maybe it had something to do with my current Java version, 1.8.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10702463/java-os-x-lion-setting-application-name-stopped-working-with-jdk1-7), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154638/setting-java-swing-application-name-on-mac), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14988628/getting-the-os-x-app-name-menu-in-java) did not work. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11734104/access-mac-os-x-application-menu-from-java), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057469/bringing-my-java-application-to-mac-os-x-menus), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884272/java-os-x-lion-about-menu) either sent me to outdated info, or the links didn't work anymore. Also, I'm running Mac 10.8.

Any suggestions/answers would be greatly appreciated.

An update:

here is the code I originally had:

```
package bouncing_off_axes;

/**
 * This is the driver class of this program.
 * 
 * @author Mason 
 *
 */

public class Main {

    /**
     * The driving method.
     * 
     * @param args
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("com.apple.mrj.application.apple.menu.about.name", "Physics Engine Practice - Bouncing Balls");
        SimulationController view = new SimulationController("Test");

    }

}
```

And here is a solution that trashgod provided to someone else:

```
package bouncing_off_axes;

    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.EventQueue;
    import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JMenu;
    import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;

    /** @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955638 */
    public class NewMain {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.setProperty("apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar", "true");
            System.setProperty(
                "com.apple.mrj.application.apple.menu.about.name", "Name");
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Gabby");
                    final JPanel dm = new JPanel() {

                        @Override
                        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                            return new Dimension(320, 240);
                        }
                    };
                    dm.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.blue, 10));

                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.add(dm);
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
                    JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
                    menuBar.add(fileMenu);
                    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

And apparently I need 10 reputation to post images, so I can't show you the result, but it didn't work out.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11915509/230513) works for me on 10.9, Java 8. For more specific help, please edit your question to include a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: @trashgod I copied verbatim the solution that you posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955638/how-do-i-move-my-jmenubar-to-the-screen-menu-bar-on-mac-os-x/8956715#8956715). The only difference is that I have the class in a non-default package, and I have the reference `package bouncing_off_axes` in the code. It did not work, the menu continued to display the class name and not the name that was set. I'll edit my post and put what I originally had and the example you provided. Also, I'd like to make this change in the code, and not on the command line.

Comment: AFAIK, the `setProperty()` approach fails with Java 8. Why not add your JAR to an application bundle, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14485964/230513)?

Comment: Ah, I see. I thought that might be the case. I was hoping not to have to add it to an application bundle, but if that's the only way to go, I may just hold off on it until I actually finish my project. This one in particular was just me doing some physics engine practice so when I'm coding the game I intend to work on, it can all be fresher in my mind.

Comment: I've elaborated below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using Java 8 on Mac OS X 10.9, setting the `System` property

```
System.setProperty("com.apple.mrj.application.apple.menu.about.name", "Name");
```

appears to be ineffectual in changing the name displayed in the application menu. Alternatives that still work include these:

- By default, the application menu will display the simple name of the class specified in the `java` command line or the `Main-Class` attribute of the JAR's manifest.

  ```
   java -cp build/classes mypackage.Name
   java -jar dist/MyJar.jar
  ```
- Use the `-Xdock:name="Name"` command line parameter.

  ```
  java -Xdock:name="Name" -cp build/classes mypackage.Main
  java -Xdock:name="Name" -jar MyJar.jar
  ```
- Add the application JAR to a Mac application bundle, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14485964/230513), an add the attribute to the `Info.plist`.

  ```
  <key>JVMOptions</key>
  <string>-Xdock:name=Name</string>
  ```

Comment: I am creating my jar using the gradle plugin. Is it possible to name the application with that approach? Currently it just picks up the name of the main class.

Comment: As all three approaches shown are extra-linguistic, platform-dependent mechanisms, I don't know why not; you might ask in [tag:gradle].